# How would you solve differential equation $\rho'(t) = 1 + \cos(t) - \rho(t)$ given particular solution in the form $B\cos(t) + C\sin(t) + D$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics

I am stuck at the following differential equation
$$\frac{d \rho}{dt} = 1 + \cos(t) - \rho $$

Solve the non-homogenous rate equation for $\rho(t)$ given the initial condition: $\rho(t)=\rho_{0}$ at $t=0$.

Hint: seek a particular solution in the form:
$$B\cos(t) + C\sin(t) + D$$
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried substituting $\rho = B \cos t + C \sin t + D$?

Answer (score 1):

$$y'+y=1+\cos t$$
Solve the homogeneous equaion first:
$$y'+y=0 \implies r+1=0 \implies r=-1$$
$$\implies y_h(t)=c_1e^{-t}$$
Plug the particular solution $y_p=B\cos(t) + C\sin(t) + D $ you 're given in the DE and find the constants.
$$y'+y=1 +\cos t$$
$$(B\cos(t) + C\sin(t) + D )'+B\cos(t) + C\sin(t) + D =1+\cos t$$

Then the solution to the DE is:
$$y(t)=y_h(t)+y_p(t)$$

Comment: Thanks so much. That makes sense now that I see it. Very helpful

Comment: You're welcome ...Then your solution is the sum of the homogeneous solution and the particular one. @RowanEnglish